# Getting dailymotion video URI from URL for downloading

Tags: java, android, url, dailymotion-api

I can't download the video from the video URL. As I understand, I have to get a URI to download the video but I am unable to find the URI from the Dailymotion url using Dailymotion API.

`URL url = new URL ("https://www.dailymotion.com/video/" + dataSet.get(position).getId());
URI uri = url.toURI();   //I need URI value here
downloadVideoFromURI();`

I have tried the dailymotion api but it does not give the video uri as per my knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

You can download by using this URL:

As a result, you will receive JSON Object

```
https://www.dailymotion.com/json/video/<VIDEO ID>?playlist=<PLAY LIST ID>&fields=title,stream_h264_sd_url
```

For Example:

https://www.dailymotion.com/json/video/x83iqpl?playlist=x6wzqs&fields=title,stream_h264_sd_url

OR only video

```
https://www.dailymotion.com/json/video/<VIDEO ID>?fields=title,stream_h264_sd_url
```

For Example:

https://www.dailymotion.com/json/video/x83iqpl?fields=title,stream_h264_sd_url

Comment: this answere is working fine

Answer (score 1):

Dailymotion doesn't allow users to download videos.

If you are a partner you can only download your own videos through your partner space: https://dailymotion.com/partner.

If you are a verified partner, you can contact your content manager to find a way to have more details